# Passing the correct context to a function with arguments from ready function

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I have spent a day trying to find the way to pass the correct context to the `removeForm`. The goal is to use the `removeForm` which is called when pressing `<a class="remove_2"> remove </a>` link to remove the content of the class passed to `removeForm` in this case "subform2". Here is what I tried:

```js
function removeForm(tgsubf) {
    var $removedForm = $(this).closest(tgsubf);
    var removedIndex = parseInt($removedForm.data('index'));
    $removedForm.remove();
}
    
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.remove_2').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        removeForm('.subform2')
    });
}
```

```html
<div class="subform2">
    <a class="remove_2"> remove </a>
</div>
```

I know that the context depends on how I call the function but also if I call the function using `removeForm('subform2')` I still have this problem.
The full example is hosted [here](https://gist.github.com/giacomomarchioro/f6f3d80d7d48bf8bc8e92486966b7ef3).

Comment: Your question is confusing. You said: " I would like the context to be set to the class contained in the variable `tgsubf`" but you are doing `$(this).closest(tcl)`. `$(this).closest(selector)` gets the closest ancestor, not the closest descendant. You might want to break your first statement and elaborate what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: @FrankFajardo thanks a lot for your kind comment, I've tried to clarify the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the `.subform2` element that contains the `.remove_2` which was clicked, you can do the following.

When your are inside an event callback you pass to jQuery, `this` (generally) holds the element that received the event. So you should change your code to have the following:

```
$('.remove_2').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    removeForm(this)  // <-- 'this' will refer to $('.remove_2')
});
```

Then you can change your `removeForm()` to get the immediate ancestor of the element passed to it (which would be `.remove_2`) that has `.subform2` for class and remove it, like this:

```
function removeForm(anchor) {
    var $removedForm = $(anchor).closest('.subform2');
    $removedForm.remove();
}
```

**UPDATE**

You should be able to pass a selector to `removeForm` to identify the ancestor, like this:

```
function removeForm(el, ancestorSelector) {
    // Do check to ensure ancestorSelector is provided, before using it.
    var $removedForm = $(el).closest(ancestorSelector);
    $removedForm.remove();
}
```

You can update how you call it like this:

```
$('.remove_2').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    removeForm(this, '.subform2')  // <-- 'this' will refer to $('.remove_2')
});
```

Comment: Thanks Frank, however  I would like to be able to use the argument for reusing the function for removing other classes, can I still pass the argument instead of hardcoding the class?

Comment: @GM, did my update answer your question in the comment?